# Play! Framework generate the CRUD from existing Entity

Tags: java, playframework, crud

I have an existing Entity class that already inherits from another class, not model.
The existing entity class comes from libraries (jar), that means that I can not change them.

Can I still use the CRUD approach of Play! Framework?

how can i do it?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqr

**Non-Entity Superclasses**

> Entities may have non-entity superclasses, and these superclasses can
>   be either abstract or concrete. The state of non-entity superclasses
>   is non-persistent, and any state inherited from the non-entity
>   superclass by an entity class is non-persistent. Non-entity
>   superclasses may not be used in EntityManager or Query operations. Any
>   mapping or relationship annotations in non-entity superclasses are
>   ignored.

I believe the only way is too have you super class annotated with [@MappedSuperClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516329/is-it-possible-to-build-a-jpa-entity-by-extending-a-pojo)

Comment: Sorry, but it's not an answer for my question

Comment: I assume you are talking about the crud module. You can use CRUD on your own class but since your super class is not part of the JPA model you won't be able to add crud support to it. you can add crud support to your base class though. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide7

Comment: Yes, i talking about the CRUD module.
It is a pity, because the entity, that I have, come from the .jar, and can not change them.

Comment: Is there any chance you could decompile it and add annotations?