# Separating JPA information from POJO

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I am working on a project that will have entities persisted to a database using JPA. We will be using Maven as the project management framework. I am wondering if it would be possible to create one project for the POJOs and another for the persistence definitions and then "combine" the two into a single output that contains the POJOs and their persistence information.

Basically I am trying to separate the code that POJOs from the persistence definition. Because the POJOs may be reused by several different projects that may or may not need to persist them and may or may not want to change the persistence information. (Similar but not quite the same as [Is it possible to build a JPA entity by extending a POJO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516329/is-it-possible-to-build-a-jpa-entity-by-extending-a-pojo))

I have two ideas on how I might be able to do it. If I were to use the POJOs in a web application I could provide persistence.xml and map the classes in that project and just add a dependency to the project containing the POJOs. But if I wanted to create a single jar file containing the persistence information and the POJOs, I think I could use the shade plugin?

Is there any other way to essentially merge two maven projects into a single output and is this a reasonable thing to want to do?

Comment: Why to you need JPA classes in non-JPA applications? There will be fields such technical primary keys, version fields for optimistic locking etc. which might not make any sense outside a JPA application and probably shouldn't be accessed.

Comment: That is sort of the point. I don't really need JPA in a non JPA application. These classes may be reused in applicatoins that do not need to persist the data or would like to change how it is persisted.

So, I am thinking I would like to separate the JPA content (mappings, annotations etc) from the rest of my object model.

Yes, there may be some unnecessary members such as id but I could probably (and maybe I should) resolve that by making the entity classes extensions of the POJO and map them as Mapped Superclasses.

... and maybe I should not over engineer things until I have more need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do appreciate the input. In the end, the solution for me was to create two projects. The first provided the definition of the POJOs without any JPA information. Yes there are some JPA related members such as id but I will address those. The second project contained the JPA metadata (orm and persistence XML files).

As for the members related to persistence (e.g. id) I could probably live with those in the model classes but using the suggestion in this post ([Is it possible to build a JPA entity by extending a POJO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516329/is-it-possible-to-build-a-jpa-entity-by-extending-a-pojo)) I extended my POJO classes and declared id in the "entity" sub classes. This does require some consideration when defining the POJO in terms of access to members.

One thing to note, this solution runs into trouble when you have a class hierarchy (inheritance in your model). The classes in your "pure" model inherit from some common class. That class is then extended in the "persistence" model to provide the id and other persistence related members. Now if the persistent subclasses inherit from the classes in the "pure" model, they do not inherit the id and other persistent members.

There may be workarounds in different inheritance mapping such as table per concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, then annotations do not have to be on the classpath if you're not using them. The annotated classes can still be loaded.

So my recommendation would be:

- Stick with the JPA annotations, as this is the easiest way to define the mappings and tooling support is usually better.
- Declare the JPA dependencies as **optional** and probably also as **provided**.
- If you need to override the mappings defined by the annotations, it should be possible to do this using the persistence.xml, AFAIK (never tried).

Comment: I believe you are correct about overriding the annotations with persistence.xml.That was one approach I had taken. But there is something about adding the annotations and additional dependencies knowing that in some cases they may not be needed or wanted that seems wrong to me.

Comment: @user1723105 That's why I recommend to declare the JPA dependencies as optional.